# Movilizer - Send data to bluetooth printer

Tags: printing, bluetooth, sap-basis, movilizer

I have the requirement of print a ticket from a Movelet. The printer will be connected via bluetooth to the device.

Is it possible to do this task on Movilizer for SAP?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
David.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, check [btspp:// in SPI documentation](https://devtools.movilizer.com/confluence/display/DOC25/Module+SPI+Connection+feature)